# API get requests same path different parameters. How to name it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

I have 2 get methods. Paths are like below:

```
lists/:user_id
lists/:list_id
```

But I can access just one of them. How should I structure it? Should it be like this:

```
lists/:user_id
lists/:user_id/list_id
```

How should endpoints look like?

Answer (score 2):

Add entity type:

`users/:id` / `lists/:id`

*or*

`lists/users/:id` / `lists/lists/:id`